# Variadic template argument list with changing return type

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic

I am trying to make a templated variadic with a changing return type.
If the number of arguments is 1 then it should return a pointer to the only argument, otherwise it should return a tuple of pointer of the argument:

```
int var = 0;
A *ptr_A = foo<A>(var);
auto *[ptr_A, ptr_B] = foo<A, B>(var);
```

and this is the code i have so far

```
template<typename T>
T* AddComp(EntityId entityID)
{
    componentPool<T>* pool = GetOrCreatePool<T>();
    return pool->Create(entityID);
}

template <typename... Args>
decltype(auto) AddComponent(EntityId entityID)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Args) == 1)
    {
        return AddComp <Args>(entityID);
    }
    else
    {
        return std::tuple<decltype(AddComponent<Args>({}))... > {AddComponent<Args>(entityID)...};
    }
}
```

But i am getting several errors:

In case of `A *ptr_A = foo<A>(var);` VS says that he cannot convert from void to A*, which says that decltype(auto) is somehow becoming void

And in `return AddComp <Args>(entityID);` VS says that Args parameter pack must be expanded. Do i still need to somehow expand Args even if its a single parameter?

Thank you!

Edit:

As asked i am providing a minimal example

```cpp
using EntityId = size_t;

class A
{
public:

int a;
};

class B
{
public:

int b;
};

class componentsManager
{
    
public:

template<typename T>
T* AddComp(EntityId entityID)
{
    return new T();
}

template <typename... Args>
decltype(auto) AddComponent(EntityId entityID)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Args) == 1)
    {
        return AddComp <Args>(entityID);
    }
    else
    {
        return std::tuple<decltype(AddComponent<Args>({}))... > {AddComponent<Args>(entityID)...};
    }
}
    
};

componentsManager m_manager;
EntityId id;

A *ptr_A1 = m_manager.AddComponent <A>(id);
auto *[ptr_A2, ptr_B] =  m_manager.AddComponent<A, B>(id);// This will only compile in c++17 i believe, i am using c++14
```

Edit2:

Error i get in VS 2019
[image: VSError]

Comment: You need `return AddComp<Args...>(entityID);`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yeah i tried to add the expansion `...` before but i get an error saying "expected a >".

Comment: Can you please make a [mre]?

Comment: @cigien i added an example i believe can be useful

Comment: You say you are using C++14, but you are relying on C++17 features throughout, e.g. `if constexpr`. Can you, or can't you, use C++17? Pre-C++17, you'd need two overloads.

Comment: Plain vanilla `if constexpr (sizeof...(Args) == 1) { return AddComp<Args...>(entityID); }` compiles fine for me, with clang and MSVC. You say you've seen an error when you tried that: what was the error?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I can use C++17, but i much rather prefer (if possible) a solution in C++14 since i would have to fix some 3rd party libraries in order to compile to C++17.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I have added a screenshot of the error. I changed the version to C++17 and i still get that error

Comment: Do you get an error when you actually compile this code? It could be IntelliSense is just getting confused.

Comment: Yeah i get the error when compiling: ```E0439: expected a '> ```'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straightforward

```
if constexpr (sizeof...(Args) == 1)
{
    return AddComp<Args...>(entityID);
}
```

appears to work just fine. [Clang demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7W3oMa), [MSVC demo](https://godbolt.org/z/887Mdo)

---

Here's a solution that works with C++14:

```
template <typename T>
decltype(auto) AddComponent(EntityId entityID)
{
  return AddComp<T>(entityID);
}

template <typename... Args>
decltype(auto) AddComponent(
    std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(Args) > 1), EntityId> entityID)
{
    return std::tuple<decltype(AddComponent<Args>({}))...>{
        AddComponent<Args>(entityID)...};
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/h7jYjY)

Comment: Works perfectly. It was IntelliSense wrongly throwing that error due to a wrong forwarding.